# How can I fix this dependency error when updating clamav using yum?

Tags: centos, yum, upgrade, dependencies

I'm trying to update `clamav` on an old CentOS 5 mail server installation, but keep getting a dependency error which I can't understand.

I followed the method described [here](https://github.com/vrtadmin/clamav-faq/blob/master/faq/Upgrading.md).

Perhaps someone can show me the way through this?

```
[root@s1 ~]# yum list clamav
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, priorities
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: centos.mirror.facebook.net
 * extras: centos-distro.cavecreek.net
 * rpmforge: mirror.hmc.edu
 * updates: mirror.thelinuxfix.com
base                                                                                                                                                                                                      | 1.1 kB     00:00     
dag                                                                                                                                                                                                       | 1.9 kB     00:00     
extras                                                                                                                                                                                                    | 2.1 kB     00:00     
rpmforge                                                                                                                                                                                                  | 1.9 kB     00:00     
updates                                                                                                                                                                                                   | 1.9 kB     00:00     
Excluding Packages in global exclude list
Finished
Installed Packages
clamav.i386                                                                                               0.97.6-1.el5.rf                                                                                               installed
clamav.i386                                                                                               0.97.7-1.el5.rf                                                                                               installed
[root@s1 ~]# 



[root@s1 ~]# yum update clamav
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, priorities
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: centos.mirror.facebook.net
 * extras: centos-distro.cavecreek.net
 * rpmforge: mirror.hmc.edu
 * updates: mirror.thelinuxfix.com
base                                                                                                                                                                                                      | 1.1 kB     00:00     
dag                                                                                                                                                                                                       | 1.9 kB     00:00     
extras                                                                                                                                                                                                    | 2.1 kB     00:00     
rpmforge                                                                                                                                                                                                  | 1.9 kB     00:00     
updates                                                                                                                                                                                                   | 1.9 kB     00:00     
Excluding Packages in global exclude list
Finished
Setting up Update Process
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
--> Processing Dependency: clamav = 0.97.6-1.el5.rf for package: clamd
---> Package clamav.i386 0:0.97.7-1.el5.rf set to be updated
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
clamd-0.97.6-1.el5.rf.i386 from installed has depsolving problems
  --> Missing Dependency: clamav = 0.97.6-1.el5.rf is needed by package clamd-0.97.6-1.el5.rf.i386 (installed)
Error: Missing Dependency: clamav = 0.97.6-1.el5.rf is needed by package clamd-0.97.6-1.el5.rf.i386 (installed)
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: package-cleanup --problems
                        package-cleanup --dupes
                        rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
[root@s1 ~]#
```

The above results are obtained after running the suggested:

```
package-cleanup --problems
package-cleanup --dupes
rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

I ran `yum --disablerepo=\* --enablerepo=rpmforge update clam\*` in accordance with an answer and received the following terminal output:

```
[root@s1 ~]# yum --disablerepo=\* --enablerepo=rpmforge update clam\*
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, priorities
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * rpmforge: mirror.hmc.edu
rpmforge                                                                                | 1.9 kB     00:00     
Excluding Packages in global exclude list
Finished
Setting up Update Process
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package clamav.i386 0:0.97.7-1.el5.rf set to be updated
---> Package clamav-db.i386 0:0.97.7-1.el5.rf set to be updated
---> Package clamd.i386 0:0.97.7-1.el5.rf set to be updated
--> Finished Dependency Resolution

Dependencies Resolved

===============================================================================================================
 Package                   Arch                 Version                         Repository                Size
===============================================================================================================
Updating:
 clamav                    i386                 0.97.7-1.el5.rf                 rpmforge                 2.2 M
 clamav-db                 i386                 0.97.7-1.el5.rf                 rpmforge                  34 M
 clamd                     i386                 0.97.7-1.el5.rf                 rpmforge                 243 k

Transaction Summary
===============================================================================================================
Install       0 Package(s)
Upgrade       3 Package(s)

Total download size: 37 M
Is this ok [y/N]: y
Downloading Packages:
(1/3): clamd-0.97.7-1.el5.rf.i386.rpm                                                   | 243 kB     00:00     
(2/3): clamav-0.97.7-1.el5.rf.i386.rpm                                                  | 2.2 MB     00:00     
(3/3): clamav-db-0.97.7-1.el5.rf.i386.rpm                                               |  34 MB     00:03     
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Total                                                                          9.0 MB/s |  37 MB     00:04     
Running rpm_check_debug
Running Transaction Test
Finished Transaction Test


Transaction Check Error:
  package clamav-db-0.97.7-1.el5.rf.i386 is already installed
  package clamd-0.97.7-1.el5.rf.i386 is already installed
  package clamav-0.97.7-1.el5.rf.i386 is already installed

Error Summary
-------------

[root@s1 ~]#
```

Installed packages, according to `yum list clam\*` are:

```
clamav.i386                                         0.97.6-1.el5.rf                                   installed
clamav.i386                                         0.97.7-1.el5.rf                                   installed
clamav-db.i386                                      0.97.6-1.el5.rf                                   installed
clamav-db.i386                                      0.97.7-1.el5.rf                                   installed
clamd.i386                                          0.97.6-1.el5.rf                                   installed
clamd.i386                                          0.97.7-1.el5.rf                                   installed
Available Packages
clamav-devel.i386                                   0.97.7-1.el5.rf                                   dag      
clamav-milter.i386                                  0.97.7-1.el5.rf                                   dag      
clamtk.i386                                         3.09-1.el5.rf                                     dag      
clamtk.noarch                                       4.25-1.el5.rf                                     dag
```

Why am I still seeing `0.97.6-1.el5.rf` in the list?

Comment: @slm It's 64 bit.

Comment: @sim CentOS 5. I have no idea whether rpmforge was added by me, CentOS or the server provisioning, but it seems that that was where it was obtained. Just need to upgrade it though.

Comment: So the million dollar question is what happens when you give the command `yum --disablerepo=\* --enablerepo=rpmforge remove clam\*-0.97.6-1.el5.rf`?

Comment: I reckon that has completed the answer. All went smoothly. If you'd like to update your answer, I'll be pleased to accept it.

Comment: Updated my answer, glad to help you out of your predicament 8-).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My first guess would be that you're mixing YUM repositories. Notice that the RPM for clamav as a `.rf.` in its name which signifies that it's a rpmforge package. I'd confirm that clamd also is a rpmforge package and not coming from one of the other repos.

The error message is basically telling you this, saying that it can't find an appropriate package, `clamd...rf...`.

#### Focus only on rpmforge repo

You can disable every repo temporarily and enable just the rpmforge repo like this:

```
$ yum --disablerepo=\* --enablerepo=rpmforge update clam\*
```

The above command will allow yum to do an update against just the one repo (rpmforge).

#### Duplicate RPMs

If you encounter duplicate versions of the `clam*` RPMS installed as the OP experienced the following command can be used to identify the situation:

```
$ yum list clam\*
clamav.i386                                         0.97.6-1.el5.rf                                   installed
clamav.i386                                         0.97.7-1.el5.rf                                   installed
clamav-db.i386                                      0.97.6-1.el5.rf                                   installed
clamav-db.i386                                      0.97.7-1.el5.rf                                   installed
clamd.i386                                          0.97.6-1.el5.rf                                   installed
clamd.i386                                          0.97.7-1.el5.rf  
...
...
```

This command will resolve that issue by removing the duplicate packages:

```
$ yum --disablerepo=\* --enablerepo=rpmforge remove clam\*-0.97.6-1.el5.rf
```

#### References

- [Repositories in CentOS](http://wiki.centos.org/AdditionalResources/Repositories)

Comment: I've just tried both commands above but the error message is identical to the above for both of them. According to `yum list clamav` I have 2 installed and they are both `.rf` packages and bewilderingly, `clamav = 0.97.6-1.el5.rf is needed by package clamd-0.97.6-1.el5.rf.i386 (installed)`

Comment: @sim What's the risk with doing that? Is it likely re-install correctly in to mailserver apps?

Comment: I've just checked the origin of clamd using `yum list clamd` and both of the two showing as installed are rpmforge packages also.

Comment: Yeah in CentOS 6 it became a standard offering from the el6 repos. My CentOS 5 boxes are showing it coming from rpmforge so that isn't the issue.

Comment: I've updated my question with the result of trying your latest edit.